# The following reference has been added to the project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was adding a `PersianDateControl` to my project and removed it after two days. Now I want to add that control to my project again, but this dialog doesn't allow me to add it.

> The following reference has been added to the project:
>   "PersianDateControls, Version =1.2.4495.22344, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=Null"
>
> In order to use types from the new references, press ok to restart the XAML designer, after the XAML designer restarts, re-create the control on the artboard

Now what should I do?

Comment: Did you restart designer?

Comment: how restart designer?

Comment: Restart the Visual Studio and see if you are getting same error.

Comment: yes i restarted Visual Studio many time but ...

Comment: Open the `.csproj ` file in notepad and see if there is already reference for this package.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectView>ProjectFiles</ProjectView>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Comment: this is .csproj contain in notepad

Comment: Does it have no reference? It's not complete `.csproj` file. Can you try to copy the source code to a new folder and see if error still exist.

Comment: It's complete .csproj file